# Notification on failed upload on aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading log data to aws s3 bucket daily. Is there any way to get notified when due to some condition data is not being uploaded in s3 bucket for some day?

Comment: did you try something ? Which language do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no notifications for actions that didn't occur -- such as an upload that S3 refused because the content didn't match the `Content-MD5` header due to data corruption, or unauthorized access, or invalid signatures, or excessive clock skew on the system that signed the request, or network connectivity failures, or any number of other factors that might prevent a successful upload.

Some, but not all, of these would appear in the bucket's access log.

The only way to find an upload that didn't happen would involve your own code, doing heuristic analysis to detect problems.

For example, if a system is supposed to send logs with sequential numbers, throw a warning if log number *n* arrives but you have no record of receiving log number *n-1*.  Or, if a log should arrive every 5 minutes, throw a warning if no log has arrived for a period ((5 + (5 × 2)) ÷ 2) minutes.  Both of these scenarios might be best handled using a separate database for state-tracking.